# Packaging Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable into an InstalLShield setup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, redistributable

I have developed a software with visual studio 2012 using the c++ language. I use Installshield 2010 Premier to build my setup project. I am trying to package the visual studio 2012 redistributable into the setup package so that it installs automatically. Is there a way to do this? I cannot find the redistributable in question on the redistributable page while configuring the installer.

Can I add it manually?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Currently, I'm just manually running the redistributable I downloaded from Microsoft page before I run the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to read first:

You need to install IS2012 SP1 to get these prereqs.  See:

[InstallShield 2012 Spring Service Pack 1 is Now Available!](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2012/09/installshield-2012-spring-service-pack-1-is-now-available.html)

Otherwise the PRQ XML can be found at:

[x86 PRQ XML On Saturn](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft%20visual%20c++%202012%20redistributable%20package%20%28x86%29.prq)

[x64 PRQ XML On Saturn](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft%20visual%20c++%202012%20redistributable%20package%20%28x64%29.prq)

Additional background information:

InstallShield comes with a prerequisite editor that you can use to define your own PRQ files.   For a tutorial see:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)

Note: The PRQ schema hasn't changed in a long time.  You can frequently install a trial version of InstallShield on a VM, find a new/updated PRQ and then back port it to your 2010 environment.  Add it, build and test and it usually works fine.  Also sometimes InstallShield will have expansion packs and addon installers to add these without rereleasing the product.

Comment: Where did you find these PRQ XML links? Is there a way to download a complete update, or get a directory listing?

Comment: You install a demo version of InstallShield and then search for .PRQ files and go snooping.  It isn't documented.  They are resources for licensed InstallShield customers and their customers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the redistributable merge modules (*.msm files) to integrate them into your setup.  If you have Visual Studio installed you can find them at `Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules` .

Comment: I don't suggest using the merge modules due to various servicing issues.  Use the prereq instead.